# Have to manually click on the search button before clicking programmatically

Tags: javascript, dom, youtube

I am trying to create a simple JS function that searches for a given string on youtube and returns the first result. I plan to run it in the console of the tab which has youtube opened. This is my code

```
const fetchLink = ()=>{
    allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    allInputs[0].value="Live Fast"
    
    // Fetch button
    document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy").click()
}
```

I open youtube.com in my browser, I put this function in the console and call it. It does put the value in searchbox but the click event does not get dispatched at first time. Now if I manually click on the search button then it searches and after that code works perfectly fine, including this line.

```
// Fetch button
document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy").click()
```

Unable to understand why a script won't work as intended on the first time but works perfectly fine after that first try.

Comment: I'm not certain on this, but it may be similar to how browsers restrict media from being played without user interaction in the DOM first. In other words, you cannot 'fake' clicking a link without the user first showing intent to view the page by interacting with it. If this is the case, it's a security feature at browser level which you cannot do much about.

Comment: You could use a webscraper like puppeteer for Node.js. Those can actually simulate user clicks

Comment: Sure but I'd still want to do it using JS if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out why this happens, do the following steps in order in console when youtube open

1-

```
const searchButton = document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy")
```

2-

```
const logEvent = (e)=>console.log(e)
```

3-

```
searchButton.addEventListener('click',logEvent)
```

after define these things,one time click on search button and one time run your code:

```
const fetchLink = ()=>{
allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
allInputs[0].value="Live Fast"

// Fetch button
document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy").click()
}

document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy").click()
```

you can see in console two log of event  and the different between them is a property that called isTrusted .
The isTrusted read-only property of the Event interface is a boolean value that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via EventTarget.dispatchEvent().[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted)

in the end i think there is a code like this in youtub source code that prevent search if event not trusted

```
  if (e.isTrusted) {
      /* do search */
     } else {
      /* return */
   }
```

Comment: That was a really clever way to see the issue, thanks for the help. I now understand the why, now I'll try for a workaround